# jQuery Slide in the Wrong Position

Tags: jquery, coda-slider

I've [followed the tutorial](http://jqueryfordesigners.com/coda-slider-effect/) on jQuery for Designers about how to create a slider similar to Coda.

Anyway, it worked first time and is great apart from one thing. The position of the last panel always seems to be in the wrong place. Here is the code that I'm using (this is a local WordPress installation by the way, so I can't show you an example of the work):

```
<div id="carousel">
<div class="scroll">
    <div class="scrollContainer">
        <p class="panel" id="slide1">Guerrilla marketing solutions that will blow your mind into a thousand million pieces and then earn you <span>shit loads of money</span>.</p>
        <p class="panel" id="slide2">Guerrilla marketing solutions that will blow your mind into a thousand million pieces and then earn you <span>shit loads of money</span>.</p>
        <p class="panel" id="slide3">Guerrilla marketing solutions that will blow your mind into a thousand million pieces and then earn you <span>shit loads of money</span>.</p>
        <p class="panel" id="slide4">Guerrilla marketing solutions that will blow your mind into a thousand million pieces and then earn you <span>shit loads of money</span>.</p>
        <p class="panel" id="slide5">Guerrilla marketing solutions that will blow your mind into a thousand million pieces and then earn you <span>shit loads of money</span>.</p>
    </div><!--/scrollContainer-->
</div><!--/scroll-->
<ul>
    <li><a href="#slide1">1</a></li>
    <li>/</li>
    <li><a href="#slide2">2</a></li>
    <li>/</li>
    <li><a href="#slide3">3</a></li>
    <li>/</li>
    <li><a href="#slide4">4</a></li>
    <li>/</li>
    <li><a href="#slide5">5</a></li>
</ul>
<a href="<?php bloginfo('url');?>/contact/" title="Get in Touch" id="carouselCTA"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/images/get-in-touch-button.png" alt="Get in Touch Button" /></a>
```

```
// bind the navigation clicks to update the selected nav:
$('#carousel ul').find('a').click(selectNav);

// handle nav selection - lots of nice chaining :-)
function selectNav() {
  $(this)
    .parents('ul:first') // find the first UL parent
      .find('a') // find all the A elements
        .removeClass('selected') // remove from all
      .end() // go back to all A elements
    .end() // go back to 'this' element
    .addClass('selected');
}

function trigger(data) {
  // within the .navigation element, find the A element
  // whose href ends with ID ($= is ends with)
  var el = $('#carousel ul').find('a[href$="' + data.id + '"]').get(0);

  // we're passing the actual element, and not the jQuery instance.
  selectNav.call(el);
}

if (window.location.hash) {
  trigger({ id : window.location.hash.substr(1)});
} else {
  $('#carousel ul a:first').click();
}   

// when the DOM is ready...
$(document).ready(function () {

var $panels = $('#carousel .scrollContainer > p');
var $container = $('#carousel .scrollContainer');

// if false, we'll float all the panels left and fix the width 
// of the container
var horizontal = true;

// float the panels left if we're going horizontal
if (horizontal) {
  $panels.css({
    'float' : 'left',
    'position' : 'relative' // IE fix to ensure overflow is hidden
  });

  // calculate a new width for the container (so it holds all panels)
  $container.css('width', $panels[0].offsetWidth * $panels.length);
}

// collect the scroll object, at the same time apply the hidden overflow
// to remove the default scrollbars that will appear
var $scroll = $('#carousel .scroll').css('overflow', 'hidden');


// handle nav selection
function selectNav() {
  $(this)
    .parents('ul:first')
      .find('a')
        .removeClass('selected')
      .end()
    .end()
    .addClass('selected');
}

$('#carousel ul').find('a').click(selectNav);

// go find the navigation link that has this target and select the nav
function trigger(data) {
  var el = $('#carousel ul').find('a[href$="' + data.id + '"]').get(0);
  selectNav.call(el);
}

if (window.location.hash) {
  trigger({ id : window.location.hash.substr(1) });
} else {
  $('ul a:first').click();
}

// offset is used to move to *exactly* the right place, since I'm using
// padding on my example, I need to subtract the amount of padding to
// the offset.  Try removing this to get a good idea of the effect
var offset = parseInt((horizontal ? 
  $container.css('paddingTop') : 
  $container.css('paddingLeft')) 
  || 0) * -1;


var scrollOptions = {
  target: $scroll, // the element that has the overflow

  // can be a selector which will be relative to the target
  items: $panels,

  navigation: 'ul a',

  // selectors are NOT relative to document, i.e. make sure they're unique
 // prev: 'img.left', 
  //next: 'img.right',

  // allow the scroll effect to run both directions
  axis: 'xy',

  onAfter: trigger, // our final callback

  offset: offset,

  // duration of the sliding effect
  duration: 500,

  // easing - can be used with the easing plugin: 
  // http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/
  easing: 'swing'
};

// apply serialScroll to the slider - we chose this plugin because it 
// supports// the indexed next and previous scroll along with hooking 
// in to our navigation.
$('#carousel').serialScroll(scrollOptions);

// now apply localScroll to hook any other arbitrary links to trigger 
// the effect
$.localScroll(scrollOptions);

// finally, if the URL has a hash, move the slider in to position, 
// setting the duration to 1 because I don't want it to scroll in the
// very first page load.  We don't always need this, but it ensures
// the positioning is absolutely spot on when the pages loads.
scrollOptions.duration = 1;
$.localScroll.hash(scrollOptions);

});
```

The jQuery also uses scrollTo, localScroll and serialScroll plugins.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Just for measure, here is the CSS I'm using too:

```
div.scroll {
    position:relative;
    overflow:auto;
    float:left;
    width:535px;
    height:135px;
}

.scrollContainer p.panel {
    width:535px;
    height:135px;
    font-size:32px;
    color:#fff;
}

#carousel p span {
    color:#ffc411;
}

#carousel ul {
    float:right;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    color:#b6b6b6;
}

#carousel li {
    float:left;
    margin:0 0 0 10px;
}

#carousel li a {
    color:#fff;
    text-decoration:none;
}

#carousel li a:hover, #carousel li a.selected {
    color:#b6b6b6;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a bit of a stupid one really. Rather than having Cufon target the child of #carousel, I had it targeting #carousel itself, so rather than just applying the style to itself it was applying it to a DIV. Which, of course, meant that there was a canvas tag being added beneath the carousel.

Only apply Cufon to text elements, children.

Answer (score 0):

I think your error originates from the CSS. 
Try to change this:

```
#carousel li {
    float:left;
    margin:0 0 0 10px;
}
```

to this

```
#carousel li {
    float:left;
    margin:0;
}
```

If it works, you can always make a div inside each slide, that has a 10px left margin.

Comment: Thanks for your help but that's not the problem. #carousel li is styling the navigation and has nothing to do with the slides at all. The slides are nested within divs and are not list items at all.